# Java Pattern.quote

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am pretty new to Patterns and some help would be great.

I am building a webcrawler, which looks for a specific pattern in the path.

Right now I am using `Pattern.quote` to produce a literal string.

Let's say Pattern.quote produces `\Q/test/live/167909\E` in which after the second slash (thus live) is always the same. Because `test` and `167909` is random I created this pattern `\Q/*/live/*\E` , but I can't use this to create a new Pattern.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: If the entire pattern is quoted why are you using a pattern? Its would be simpler to use regular String comparison like `String.contains()` or `String.startsWith` or `String.equals`

Comment: Did you look at [Pattern.compile(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: @sudocode yes ofcourse, but i doesnt take a literal string.

Comment: @PeterLawrey is it possible to use these methods, because half of the path is random?

Comment: See sudocode's example for contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `".*/live/.*"` matches paths with the pattern you describe. You can create a Pattern with that.

Alternatively, as Peter said, you could simply ask `path.contains("/live/");`